# Pagination with bootpag and jquery

Tags: php, jquery

the data from kontakte_data.php will not be loaded to div id="results", but i can see the database results outside the table, has someone an idea ?

html-code:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>K-ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Ort</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <div id="results"></div>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="pagination"></div>
</div>
```

ajax-code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#results").load("kontakte_data.php");
    $(".pagination").bootpag({
        total: <?php echo $pages; ?>,
        page: 1,
        maxVisible: 5,
    }).on("page", function(e, num){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#results").load("kontakte_data.php", {'page':num});
    });
});
```

Comment: You can't have a div inside the `<tbody>` like that. It's invalid HTML and will therefore be rendered outside of the table. In `<tbody>`'s, you can have `<tr>` and `<td>`.

Comment: What does the markup in `kontakte_data.php` look like?

Comment: it works, thank you, i have to put the whole table into kontakte_data.php

Comment: I think it would work if you just removed the div and gave your `<tbody>` the id instead: `<tbody id="results">`. That is if your file just returns table rows.